# Refactoring class design to convey the design intention

Tags: c#, design-patterns, class-design, ooad, template-method-pattern

I have following class design.  The complete code is available in " [How to achieve this functionality using Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462210/how-to-achieve-this-functionality-using-generics/21575319#21575319) ". The code  works fine and resolves the casting issue mentioned in " [Refactoring Code to avoid Type Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482850/refactoring-code-to-avoid-type-casting) "

In the `RetailInvestmentReturnCalculator` class, the `GetInvestmentProfit()` method utilizes `CalculateBaseProfit()` method present in `InvestmentReturnCalculator` abstract base class. This fact is not evident from the class design.

**QUESTION**

1. How to refactor this class design to convey the above mentioned fact?
2. What is the design guideline that will prevent this sort of design mistakes?

Note: [Martin Fowler: Is Design Dead?](http://martinfowler.com/articles/designDead.html) says

> What do we mean by a software architecture? To me the term architecture conveys a notion of the core elements of the system, the pieces that are difficult to change. A foundation on which the rest must be built

**Class Diagram**

[image]

**Abstract**

```
public abstract class InvestmentReturnCalculator
{
    #region Public

    public double ProfitElement { get; set; }
    public abstract double GetInvestmentProfit();

    #endregion

    #region Protected

    protected  double CalculateBaseProfit()
    {
        double profit = 0;
        if (ProfitElement < 5)
        {
            profit = ProfitElement * 5 / 100;
        }
        else
        {
            profit = ProfitElement * 10 / 100;
        }
        return profit;
    }

    #endregion
}

public abstract class InvestmentReturnCalculator<T> : InvestmentReturnCalculator where T : IBusiness
{
    public T BusinessType { get; set; }
}
```

**Concrete**

```
public class RetailInvestmentReturnCalculator : InvestmentReturnCalculator<IRetailBusiness>
{
    public RetailInvestmentReturnCalculator(IRetailBusiness retail)
    {
        BusinessType = retail;
        //Business = new BookShop(100);
    }

    public override double GetInvestmentProfit()
    {
        ProfitElement = BusinessType.GrossRevenue;
        return CalculateBaseProfit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not evident from the class design? Making the access modifier `protected`, instead of `private`, makes that evident. More importantly, perhaps, this method `GetInvestmentProfit` is not well-named, in that it does not describe the TWO separate things that it does... Perhaps it should be renamed? how about `SetProfitElementAndCalculateProfit()` ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana Thanks for the `private` idea. Isn't `the TWO separate things` in a method something to be refactored?

Comment: Generally methods, classes, etc. should do ONE thing, and do it well.  This is called the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).  And it is a very good general principle to follow.  However, as you move up and down in the stack, what "ONE THING" actually means can change as the level of abstraction changes.  AT a high Level this might be "Order a book".  Several layers down, it might mean adjust inventory, Move book to shipping, Send invoice, etc.   But at each level, a single method should be responsible for completing a single task at that level of abstraction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ProfitElement` field is rather ugly. I would make it an abstract property on `InvestmentReturnCalculator` and implement it in base classes (rather than setting the value) - this is called the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Then you don't need the `GetInvestmentProfit()` method.

```
public abstract class InvestmentReturnCalculator
{
    #region Public

    public abstract double ProfitElement { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Protected

    public double GetInvestmentProfit()
    {
        double profit = 0;
        if (ProfitElement < 5)
        {
            profit = ProfitElement * 5 / 100;
        }
        else
        {
            profit = ProfitElement * 10 / 100;
        }
        return profit;
    }

    #endregion
}

public abstract class InvestmentReturnCalculator<T> : InvestmentReturnCalculator where T : IBusiness
{
    public T BusinessType { get; set; }
}

public class RetailInvestmentReturnCalculator : InvestmentReturnCalculator<IRetailBusiness>
{
    public RetailInvestmentReturnCalculator(IRetailBusiness retail)
    {
        BusinessType = retail;
        //Business = new BookShop(100);
    }

    public override double ProfitElement {get { return BusinessType.GrossRevenue;}}

}
```

Comment: Nice solution. However is it Template `Method` pattern? We are overriding `property` in the derived class (which eventually be called by base class); not `method` isn't it?

Comment: Also, `override` keyword is missing for ProfitElement in the derived class. And `GetInvestmentProfit()` should be made `public`

Comment: @Lijo, thanks for the comments, fixed the bugs. Regarding your first comment, we are overriding a getter, which is a method. A property is just a syntactic sugar around the pair of methods: getter + setter.